Dart not executing Code after SFTP operation
I'am new to flutter programming and want to connect my RaspberryPI to my wifi via an app and then get the new assigned IP adress of the Raspberry PI to control it later.
The SSH and SFTP operations are being executed just fine but the programm ignores/doesnt execute the following lines:
message = 'Connected Successfully';
showToast(context);
await waitforipresponse();
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const MyApp());

I don't know why these Lines are not being executed.
------- This is wifisetup.sh
 #!/bin/bash
 #dietpi Wifisetup Script
 #location /mnt/dietpi_userdata/wifisetup.sh
 
 sleep 5
 
 sudo pkill lnxrouter
 
 sudo pkill hostapd
 
 sudo pkill dnsmasq
 
 sudo apt remove hostapd --yes
 
 sudo reboot
 
 #finished

------- This is the dart code

 void connectraspberrytowifi(String SSID, String? BSSID) async {
 Future<String?> openDialog() => showDialog<String>(
 context: context,
 builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
 title: Text(SSID),
 content: TextField(
 autofocus: true,
 obscureText: true,
 decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Password"),
 controller: controller,
               ),
 actions: [
 
TextButton(
child: Text('Connect'),
onPressed: submit,
                 )
               ],
             ),
       );

rasp_BSSID = BSSID;
state = false;
buttonpressed = false;
if (await reconnect() == true) {
final PW = await openDialog();
await connectraspberry(PW, SSID);
message = 'Connected Successfully';
showToast(context);
await waitforipresponse();
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const MyApp());
else {
message = 'Error';
showToast(context);
setState(() {
instruction = 'Select Raspberry';
       });
     }
   }

Future<void> waitforipresponse() async {
final server = await HttpServer.bind(Handy_IP, 8080);

print('Server läuft auf: ${server.address}:${server.port}');

await for (var request in server) {
if (request.method == 'POST' && request.uri.path == '/receive') {
var bytes = await request.fold<List<int>>(
[], (prev, element) => prev..addAll(element));
var content = utf8.decode(bytes);
setState(() {
SSH_IP = content;
         });
request.response.write('Message recieved');
await request.response.close();
else {
request.response.write('Error');
await request.response.close();
       }
    }
   }

Future<void> connectraspberry(String? PW, String SSID) async {
if (buttonpressed == true) {
buttonpressed = false;

final sftp = await client.sftp();
final file = await sftp.open('/etc/network/interfaces');

final content = await file.readBytes();
String fileContent = latin1.decode(content);

List<String> lines = fileContent.split('\n');

for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
if (lines[i].contains('wpa-ssid')) {
lines[i] = 'wpa-ssid ${SSID}';
else if (lines[i].contains('wpa-psk')) {
lines[i] = 'wpa-psk $PW';
else if (lines[i].contains('#wireless-power off')) {
lines[i] = 'wireless-power off';
else if (lines[i].contains('#wireless-mode Managed')) {
lines[i] = 'wireless-mode Managed';
         }
       }
await file.close();

String updatedContent = lines.join('\n');
final wifidata = await sftp.open('/etc/network/interfaces',
mode: SftpFileOpenMode.write);

await wifidata.writeBytes(latin1.encode(updatedContent));
await wifidata.close();

final ipdata = await sftp.open('/mnt/dietpi_userdata/wifi_setup/ip',
mode: SftpFileOpenMode.write);
await ipdata.writeBytes(latin1.encode(Handy_IP));
await ipdata.close();

await client.run(
           'sudo chmod u+x /mnt/dietpi_userdata/wifi_setup/wifisetup.sh');
await client.run('sudo /mnt/dietpi_userdata/wifi_setup/wifisetup.sh');
client.close();
     }
   }


I just don't know why it doesnt execute the lines.
